# W3 dropdown doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used the dropdown code (http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp)  directly from W3.

I pasted all three parts (HTML, CSS, JS) into my code.  My CSS and JS pages are correctly linked and working.

I am using GetSkeleton for the first time.

My code is not working.

JS:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

CSS

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background - color:
    #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: # 3e8 e41;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline - block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown - content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background - color: #f9f9f9;
  min - width: 160 px;
  box - shadow: 0 px 8 px 16 px 0 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown - content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 6 px 8 px;
  text - decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown - content a: hover {
  background - color: #f1f1f1
}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onClick="myFunction()" class="drpbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">red</a>
    <a href="#">white</a>
    <a href="#">rose</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end of dropdown div-->
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did not paste the HTML code correctly I see now.

Comment: <div class="dropdown">
      <button onClick="myFunction()" class="drpbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">red</a>
       <a href="#">white</a>
       <a href="#">rose</a>
      </div>
     </div><!--end of dropdown div--

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably due to buggy engine.

Change the class name to caps that is `Show`

```
.Show{
    display: block;
 }
```

in Js

```
function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("Show");
   }
```

Beside you need to load the code after DOm is ready. If you see the demo & click on javascript, you can see , the JavaScript is loaded in body.

That is load the javascript after your dom is ready otherwise you may see `myFunction` not defined error. If you want to load js after dom is ready, you can either use `window.onload` or include the js code near closing brace of `body` tag

```
<body>
  // rest of code
<script>
 // you js code
</script>
</body>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/bpt1kehL/3/)